# Wordpress: Integrate PHP Site with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am integrating a PHP Site into my Wordpress Installation with a Plugin. This is working fine. Now I tried to update a dropdown list with data from a mySQL DB using a "jQuery":

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        
     jQuery("#parent_cat").change(function() {
      jQuery(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
      jQuery.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
       jQuery("#sub_cat").html(data);
       jQuery('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        jQuery(this).remove();
       });
      }); 
        });

    });
    </script>
```

the html part:

```html
form method="get">
    <label for="category">Hauptkategorie</label>
    <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Unterkategorie</label>
    <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>
</form>
```

When calling the page with the "normal" (www.mysitename.com/wp-content/themes/theme/upload.php) URL then everything is working fine. But when I call the page from the "Wordpress - URL" (www.mysitename.com/upload) then the second dropdown list will never be populated.

Do I have to call the routine below alltough I am integrating a php side into my wordpress application?

```html
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

Kind Regards,

Stefan

Comment: what errors are thrown? Why are you including jQuery in a script tag on top of `wp_enqueue_script()`?

Comment: When I call the php file from wordpress, the 2nd dropdown will not be filled, allthough when I call the page directly (via URL) then, everything is working fine. Wordpress will not give me any error! I have not called "wp_enqueue_script"? Do I have to call it - alltough my php page is only called from wordpress and not really part of it? Kind Regards, Stefan

Comment: it may due to the incorrect jquery file path if you are using <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>, you may check if there are any error message in the console (chrome inspector/firebug)

Comment: Dear Katrin, you were absolut right! I had to use absolute paths on all the links. I changed it, and now everything is working! Thanks a lot! Kind Regards, Stefan

Answer (score 0):

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://domainname.com/wp-content/themes/lawyerplus/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
 jQuery("#parent_cat").change(function() {
  jQuery(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="http://www.domainname.com/wp-content/themes/lawyerplus/img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
  jQuery.get('http://domainname.com/wp-content/themes/lawyerplus/loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
   jQuery("#sub_cat").html(data);
   jQuery('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
    jQuery(this).remove();
   });
  }); 
    });

});
</script>
```

To run the jquery the links have to be absolute!